# How to wrap a QFileDialog and QPushButton in an object

Tags: python, pyqt5, qfiledialog

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import (
    QDir
)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import(
    QApplication,QDialog,
    QVBoxLayout,QGridLayout,QPushButton,QFileDialog
)

class DicAsk(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DicAsk, self).__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton("ButtonB")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.browse)
        # self.button.clicked.connect(lambda:QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Find Files",
        #     QDir.currentPath()))
    def browse(self):
        directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Find Files",
            QDir.currentPath())

class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        buttonA = QPushButton("ButtonA")
        buttonA.clicked.connect(self.browse)

        dicAsk = DicAsk()

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonA)
        mainLayout.addWidget(dicAsk.button)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def browse(self):
        directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Find Files",
            QDir.currentPath())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There are two buttons in the window: "buttonA" and "button B".
Button A works fine, it can successfully open a `QFileDialog`.

Button B is defined in a class and should work like button A, but it doesn't open a `QFileDialog`. It works if the `browse` method is changed into a lambda function. Why doesn't the `browse` method work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>The problem is that `DicAsk` is not define as a PyQt object. It's only define as a basic python class, so its methods can't be slots. `DicAsk.browse` is never called when you click button B.</s>

The real problem is that you don't keep a reference to `dicAsk`. It is defined locally in `Window.__init__`, and then destroyed. You can still use `dicAsk.buttton` because it was added to the layout (`window` becomes the parent of `dicAsk.button`, and so keeps a reference to the button)

To fix the issue you can keep a reference with `self.dicAsk=DicAsk()`, or modify the class to have a parent:

```
class DicAsk(QtCore.Qobject):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(DicAsk, self).__init__(parent)

#in Window
dicAsk=DicAsk(self)
```

Another way to solve your issue is to subclass `QPushButton`:

```
class MyButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setText("ButtonB")
        self.clicked.connect(self.browse)

    def browse(self):
        print("browse")
```

It makes more sense since what you want is a customized button.

Comment: This is not correct - *any* python callable can be used as a slot. The only thing wrong with the OPs example is that they aren't keeping a reference to `dicAsk` (the button will be reparented when it's added to the layout). But you're probably right that subclassing `QPushButton` makes more sense.

Comment: Indeed my bad. I thought I had fix the example only by using `QObject`, but I actually also added `self.dicAsk`. I will edit my answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks,this'is a perfect answer.